# ¿Es un tenedor? ¿Es una cuchara?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Acabo de llegar de una boda y antes de irme a la cama no puedo resistirme a plantearos una duda. Durante la misma me han puesto un entrante con uno de estos:

[image: Cuchador]

Y automáticamente me he acordado de la escena de Wall-E en la que el robot no puede decidirse en qué lado clasificar un cachivache similar:

[image: Teneduchara]

Pero ya en serio, ¿recibe algún nombre especial el cuchador/teneduchara de la imagen?

Comment: Yo lo uso como *cuchara para ensaladas*.

Comment: Si creemos a wikipedia, es cuchador.

Comment: spork es como lo llaman en inglés. Lo he visto traducido como  tenedor-cuchara

Comment: Tengo la sensación vaga de que esto ya se preguntó.  No recuerdo la respuesta, sin embargo.  ¿Tenedor redondeado?

Answer (score 3):

En inglés, se le conoce como *spork* y corresponde a la categoría de las *portmanteau words* cuya fusión viene de *spoon* y *fork*.

Desafortunadamente, esta palabra carece de un equivalente en español —o podemos tomar en cuenta que ya se había comentado como *cuchador*; la definición *a tool shaped like a spoon at one end and a fork at the other, used for eating food* solamente la deja para las comidas, pero no hace ninguna alusión si es que tienen algún fin particular a la hora de elegir qué tipo de comida.

Comment: ¿Qué tal `tenechara` o `cuchador` (como lo menciona Galeano en los comentarios)?

Comment: @Phi Sí. Lo puedes llamar como sea, pues no hay traducción oficial.

Answer (score 0):

La palabra en cuestión parece ser `cuchador`. No obstante, no es una traducción oficial aceptada por la RAE, ya que si la buscamos encontramos que aparece frecuentemente en artículos y blogs, y mayoritariamente entrecomillada.

Comment: Hola, ten en cuenta que lo que explicas en esta respuesta ("cuchador") ya estaba bastante presente en otra respuesta anterior. Date cuenta de que si lo que quieres es respaldar cierto contenido puedes votar esa respuesta. Si quieres ampliar ¿podrías proporcionar algún tipo de explicación o motivos de uso que mejoren la comprensión? Suele ayudar decir qué forma se usa en tu zona, dar elementos históricos que lo expliquen, etc. Más info en [answer]. En definitiva, haz tu respuesta significativamente distinta a las ya existentes. Gracias.